# How to set column width to content width in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a list of blocks, that I want to place in two rows, now I use grid:

```css
li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

li:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item1111</li>
<li>content content</li>
</ul>
```

You can see, what I get:

[image: current result]

I want to set width of every grid cell to width of its content, like on the pic [image: desired result]

Is it even possible?

Comment: Nope. Grid columns can't adapt to the content. And a flexbox solution would not align rows the way you want.

Comment: Oh I just  read your question again. You actually want the second image yeah that's possible. I'll write a flexbox solution

Comment: Might be more of a css masonry question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the rows to align you can try flexbox instead of grid:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: none;
  max-width: 9rem;
}

li {
  padding: 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Content 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>content 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what the logic behind the 9rem. It won't work if you update the content

Comment: That's a pity, thanks for your solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif Threw it in there to get it working

Answer (score -1):

set grid rows and columns to auto `grid-template-rows: auto auto;` `grid-template-columns: auto auto;`

set width of the `li`'s `width: max-content;`

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  width: 250px;
  gap:10px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #EDF6FF;
  border-radius:10px;
  width: max-content;
  color:#2E4665;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid-container">
  <li>Item11111</li>
  <li>Content11111</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The question is - perhaps - a little ambiguous, but I think OP wants the result shown in the last picture, your answer seems to reproduce the result that they already get, and don't want. But - until OP comments either way - I'm not entirely certain of that.

Comment: oh.no worries ill delete once confirmed